# Changes in stable need to be in default

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I created a stable but I accidentally changed a file while working with stable branch. I committed and now my default (which is development) doesn't have it. I tried `hg pull -r <changset>` where changeset is the latest commit.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hg merge stable
```

This will merge the two together.

Visit https://www.mercurial-scm.org/guide and go to **Merge the named branch**.

You don't have to close it.